# What is payload data in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm debugging my program to check if the value of a property is correctly set. I put a breakpoint in this function:

```
func showContent(data: Any) -> UIView {
    // breakpoint here
    var contentView = UIView()
    if let image = data as? UIImage {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = image
        contentView = imageView
    }
    if let text = data as? String {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.text = text
        contentView = label
    }
    return contentView
}
```

The value passed to this function is from a view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    calcGroupFamiliarity()
    flashCardView.linkedMemory = Memory(masteryLevel: 1, algorithm: Algorithm.algorithm1.chooseAlgorithm(), forgetRatio: 0, lastStudyTime: Date(), front: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Blue"), back: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ideas-Yellow"))
}
```

As you can see, both the `front` and the `back` are images, however, in the debugger, they both appeared as some `payload_data`, while the data type of other values such as `masteryLevel` and `algorithm` are correct:

[image]

Can somebody explain what that means? And what should I do to pass the normal image data instead?

**Update:**

This is `Memory` class:

```
class Memory: NSObject, NSCoding {

var masteryLevel: Int
var algorithm: [Int: Double]
var forgetRatio: Int
var lastStudyTime: Date
var strength: Double = 0
var front: Any
var back: Any
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Memory")

init(masteryLevel: Int, algorithm: [Int: Double], forgetRatio: Int, lastStudyTime: Date, front: Any, back: Any){
    
    self.masteryLevel = masteryLevel
    self.algorithm = algorithm
    self.forgetRatio = forgetRatio
    self.lastStudyTime = lastStudyTime
    self.front = front
    self.back = back
}

...

}
```

Comment: For payload_data, see https://medium.com/@vhart/protocols-generics-and-existential-containers-wait-what-e2e698262ab1#.947l6tczk
What does your Memory class look like?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen thanks, plz see the update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a detail of how Swift implements the `Any` type. Given that Swift can't know beforehand what you are putting into e.g. `front`, it needs to store a pointer to that object (in `payload_data_0`) as well as a pointer to metadata about the stored object's type (in `instance_type`). As far as I know, `payload_data_1` and `payload_data_2` are there as an optimization so that Swift can store up to 24-byte large structs in place rather than having to put them in a wrapper object that needs to be stored in a separate heap location.

So, to answer your question: This is neither a bug in Swift, nor an error on your side. Your data gets stored and accessed in the right way. If you would prefer to inspect `front` more easily while debugging, try

```
(lldb) po front
```

in the debugger. Alternatively, change `front`'s type to e.g. `UIImage?`. If that is not possible, you could declare a protocol

```
protocol MemoryStoreable: class { }
```

and extend every type that needs to be stored in those fields like so:

```
extension UIImage: MemoryStoreable { }
```

and declare the variable as

```
var front: MemoryStoreable?
```

Note that `MemoryStoreable` is restricted to classes, as otherwise a protocol witness would need to be stored (which is again implemented similarly to the `Any` field you observed).

Another alternative would be, if you know you'll store e.g. only images and strings in `front`, to use an enum:

```
enum MemoryStoreable {
    case `string`(String)
    case image(UIImage)
}

var front: MemoryStoreable?
```

That will still require at least 25 bytes of storage in your object (possibly 32 due to memory alignment constraints), though, as that's the size of the `String` struct.

For more details, see e.g. https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-01-exploring-swift-memory-layout-part-ii.html.

Comment: That's a very good answer, takes a little while to digest tho, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Base on @MrMage's awesome answer.

> @MrMage gave 2 suggestions on approaching this problem, it took some
>   effort for me to grasp them, for what I wanted to achieve in the
>   program, it's the perfect scenario for me to go
>   protocol-oriented-programming.
>
> Here's a really easy to understand tutorial that help me a lot:
>   [Introduction to Protocol Oriented Programming in Swift](https://medium.com/ios-geek-community/introduction-to-protocol-oriented-programming-in-swift-b358fe4974f#.bqjes7cvx)

Hopefully this can be helpful to you :)