# Trouble understanding Xcode's Variables View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Not sure if this is the right title, but since you're here:

Through a web service, I receive a JSON object.

In the Variables View of XCode, it looks like this:

[image: XCode Screen Shot]

My ultimate goal is to extract the value of key "url"

So, in for instance Javascript, I would do

```
var url = json["image"]["url"]
```

But Swift doesn't like that. I'm sure it has to do something with the dreaded  optionals. But then I still don't understand where the 'payload_data_1' etc come from.

I just started developing for iOS again, but I seem to recall that the vars in Objective-C were shown much more comprehensibly.

So, If you show me the way to that url string, I'm already happy, but I prefer to actually understand that payload stuff as well

Comment: Well, yes , even better than expected: I discovered to type 'po' in the debugger! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: Although I'm not going through why you need to use `codable`, but I seriously recommend it. anyway:

---

The json object type (in your case) is `[String: Any]?`. So calling json?["image"] will return `Any?`. you can not subscript on `Any`.

If you know the concrete type behind `Any`, you can cast it. Then the compiler lets you subscript the result again:

```
(json?["image"] as? [String: Any])?[url]
```

You may want to cast it again to an `String`

Also, you can search for the payload to see [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42130147/5623035)